# Frage zu doppeltem Genitiv

Tags: genitive

Bei folgender Satzstellung ist die doppelte Verwendung des Genitivs recht offensichtlich

> Aufgrund des Knüppels des Eseltreibers schrie der Esel.

Wie sieht die Sache bei folgender Stellung aus?

> Aufgrund des Eseltreibers *Knüppel[s]* schrie der Esel.

Meinem Sprachgefühl nach hört sich "Knüppels" da falsch an, grammatisch sollte es aber wohl richtig sein.

Wie muss der Satz korrekt lauten? Lässt sich dort evtl. der Dativ als eine Art Behelfsform verwenden (wie in "wegen dem Knüppel des Eseltreibers")?

Answer (score 10):

1. Der nachgestellte und der vorangestellte Genitiv unterscheiden sich nicht nur in bezug auf ihre Stellung. Der vorangestellte Genitiv übernimmt die Funktion eines Artikels und verhält sich nicht mehr wie ein Genitiv, sondern wie ein endungsloser Artikel, was man an der Endung des Adjektivs erkennen kann. Ebenso die Relativartikel *dessen, deren*.

> *Artikel mit Endung, schwaches Adjektiv:*
> der neu**e** Freund von Julia
>
> *Artikel ohne Endung, starkes Adjektiv:*
> ihr neu**er** Freund
> Julias neu**er** Freund
> Julia, deren neu**er** Freund einen BMW fährt

2. Nomen mit Endung *-s* im Genitiv bedürfen der Begleitung durch einen Artikel oder ein Adjektiv mit Endung. (Duden Grammatik, § 1534)

> der Konsum von Wasser
> *der Konsum Wasser**s**
> der Konsum frisch**en** Wasser**s**
> der Konsum de**s** Wasser**s**

Als Ausnahme nennt der Duden Fälle wie *Studierende beiderlei Geschlechts* und *wegen Unwetters*, wobei auch *wegen Unwetter* möglich ist.

3. Daraus folgt, daß *Knüppel* im Ausgangsbeispiel ohne *-s* stehen muß. Der vorangestellte Genitiv *des Eseltreibers* entspricht einem endungslosen Artikel, womit die unter 2. genannte Bedingung nicht erfüllt ist.

> Aufgrund des Eseltreibers Knüppel schrie der Esel.

Es bleibt die Frage, ob *Knüppel* als endungsloser Genitiv oder als Dativ zu werten ist. Ein bekannter deutscher Präskriptivist, dem es eine Herzensangelegenheit ist, daß manche Präpositionen nur mit Genitiv stehen können, muß für Fälle wie *laut Zeitungsbericht* annehmen, daß *laut* vor "unbekleidetem Hauptwort" mit dem Dativ steht ([Quelle](https://bastiansick.de/allgemein/praepositionen-die-genitiv-undoder-dativ-regieren/)).

Ich habe mich auf die – wie ich finde, interessanten - grammatischen Aspekte konzentriert. Stilistisch betrachtet sollte man so etwas wie *aufgrund des Eseltreibers Knüppel* am besten meiden.

Comment: Das klingt nach einer soliden Darlegung. Jedoch, was sagst du zu meinem Beispiel (siehe meine Antwort) mit dem Satz ***Anhand des Wirts zerbrochenen Krugs wurde der Täter überführt***? Hier das Genitiv-s am Krug wegzulassen scheint mir überhaupt nicht geraten. In meinen Ohren wird es auch nicht besser, wenn man das Adjektiv weglässt: *Anhand des Wirts Krug wurde der Täter überführt* (?). Auch dies klingt für mich noch eher akzeptable in der Form *Anhand des Wirts Krugs wurde der Täter überführt*.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann beim ersten Beispiel ist ein Adjektiv mit Endung vorhanden (*zerbrochenen*) und die Bedingung erfüllt. Für das zweite Beispiel sagt die Theorie, daß es *Krug* heißen muß, weil das Adjektiv wegfällt. In meinen Ohren klingt es ohne *-s* auch tatsächlich besser als mit – am liebsten wäre es ihnen aber ohne den vorangestellten Genitiv. (Das Beispiel ist insofern suboptimal, als man dazu neigt, *Wirtskrugs* zu hören.)

Answer (score 0):

Probieren wir's mit anderen Sätzen:

> Der Übeltäter wurde anhand des zerbrochenen Kruges überführt.
>
> Anhand des zerbrochenen Kruges wurde der Übeltäter überführt.
>
> Anhand des zerbrochenen Kruges des Wirts wurde der Übeltäter überführt.
>
> Anhand des Wirts zerbrochenen Kruges wurde der Übeltäter überführt.<sup>1</sup>

Ich schließe daraus, dass auch "wegen des Eselstreibers Knüppels" richtig ist, auch wenn es zugegebenermaßen ungewohnt klingt. Aber man redet (und schreibt) ja normalerweise auch nicht so verdreht.

---

<sup>1</sup> Die mündliche Variante *Anhand dem Wirt seinem zerbrochenen Krug wurde der Übeltäter überführt* ignorieren wir mal.